# How would I express a nested summation of n layers without expressing each individual layer?

Tags: summation

If there is a nested summation with n layers, each layer having the same starting and ending value as every other layer, and the innermost layer containing some expression, how would I express this nested summation without expressing every individual layer of the nested summation?

Comment: You mean something like this?
$$\sum_{x_1=a}^b \sum_{x_2=a}^b ... \sum_{x_n=a}^b f(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)$$?

Comment: Yes I mean something like that.

Comment: Then Fimpellizieri's answer is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Write it as follows
$$\sum_{k_1=a}^b\,\sum_{k_2=a}^b\,\dots\,\sum_{k_n=a}^b\,=\sum_{a\,\leq\, k_1,\,k_2,\,\dots,\,k_n\leq\, b}$$